# refine selections based on previous selections in XL Release

Tags: groovy, xlrelease

Currently we have XL Release kicking off a Jenkins job.  Within the Jenkins job, we have active choice parameters using a Groovy script; you select from a dropdown, and the next dropdown will dynamically update the selected parameters based on the previous selection.  We want to remove the interaction with Jenkins, and just have everything kicked off within XL Release.

There isn't a native way to do this using a template in XL Release, and although I could possibly do it as part of a scripted task(?), I'd rather keep the experience as seamless as possible.  Is there any sort of plugin that I could use to accomplish this?